# "az login" signs you in to which tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to understand the default behavior of "az login" command. Suppose I have freshly installed Azure CLI and am doing a login for the first time using the command - az login
Now say I belong to multiple tenants, which tenant will I get logged in to?

I am aware that using the --tenantId argument I can specify a tenant, but I'm trying to understand the default behavior

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like it authenticates (or attempts to) you to all tenants where you are in. For me one tenant fails because it requires MFA. This is a bit similar to what Visual Studio does.

Comment: @juunas is right. It authenticates all the tenants that your account has. And you can set the subscription do not care which tenant it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of using just the az login would authenticate and list all the available tenant associated with the user in a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple tenant associated, and didn't run
az login --tenant tenant_id

If you run Kusto Query, most likely you won't get the resource, because the right subscription will likely not attach to it.